# SQL Join múltiplas tabelas somente o 1o resultado

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

Eu tenho 3 tabelas:

> ```
> **clientes**
> cli_cliente   nome
> 50            A
> 52            B
>
> **telefones_cliente**
> cli_cliente  tel_telefone
> 50           387
> 50           386
> 50           385
> 52           400
>
> **telefones**
> tel_telefone    tel_contato
> 385             RODOLFO - COMPRAS
> 386             SONIA CONTAS A PAGAR RAMAL 201
> 387             VANESSA CONTABILIDADE RAMAL 202
> 388             (null)
> 389             (null)
> ```

Eu preciso como resultado os clientes e somente o primeiro telefone da tabela telefones_clientes para usar esta informarção pra pegar telefones.tel_telefone e telefones.tel_contato. Já fiz várias tentativas de filtrar, mas sempre me retornam todos os telefones do cliente, preciso de ajuda.
Este é meu último SQL que também não funciona.

```
SELECT
c.cli_cliente
,cli_razao_social,
tc.tel_telefone
--  ,telefones.tel_contato
  FROM
    clientes c
  JOIN telefones_cliente tc ON c.cli_cliente = (SELECT tc.cli_cliente FROM telefones_cliente, clientes c2, telefones t WHERE c2.cli_cliente=tc.cli_cliente AND tc.tel_telefone=t.tel_telefone LIMIT 1)
```

Meu resultado é este:

> ```
> cli_cliente cli_razao_social                        tel_telefone
> 50          EXACTA ENGENHARIA E ADMINISTRAÇAO LTDA  385
> 50          EXACTA ENGENHARIA E ADMINISTRAÇAO LTDA  386
> 50          EXACTA ENGENHARIA E ADMINISTRAÇAO LTDA  387
> ```

Quando preciso disto:

> ```
> cli_cliente cli_razao_social                        tel_telefone
> 49          WOOD FORM LTDA                          384
> 50          EXACTA ENGENHARIA E ADMINISTRAÇAO LTDA  387
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Sugiro que você utilize alguma função de grupo como por exemplo MAX ou MIN para retornar apenas um telefone.

Algo mais ou menos dessa forma:

```
SELECT 
   c.cli_cliente,
   c.nome,
   tc.tel_telefone 
FROM 
   clientes c 
   JOIN (
      SELECT 
         tc.cli_cliente,
         MAX(tc.tel_telefone) tel_telefone
      FROM 
         telefones_cliente tc
      GROUP BY 
         tc.cli_cliente
   ) tc ON tc.cli_cliente = c.cli_cliente
```